# Best Database on developing hybrid mobile apps

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am looking to choose a best database for my application. The data should be stored offline within the phone. I tried SQLite and Web SQL and the app remains slow on process. Any option or ideas to make my application faster? Or is there any specific database that would make the data load faster? Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the localStorage, if you don't need relationship-models and just want to store some data.
However, if you like it really fast (and therefore in-memory) give this library a shot: http://lokijs.org/#/

It seems to work with cordova (i hope you're using cordova) and as it is in-memory it's super fast.